# How to Delete a Work Item In Visual Studio Online?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there way to delete work items from the web UI?
If not, then way it is not possible?

Note: there is command line tool for that, but it is hard to use.

Comment: Why do you want to delete a work item?

Comment: My reasons for deleting work items:
1. Creating work items for training or testing VSO functionality.
2. After entering some Task work items I see later as unnecessary, So there is no need to keep them with the 'removed' state because this items are useless info in the system.

Comment: You should always do 'training' in a separate Team Project. Then it can simply be deleted. Ideally you should use a separate collection.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. You need to use the witadmin command line tool.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236908.aspx

However, you should think twice and instead use the 'removed' state. Deleting work items removes traceability, especially if you have artifacts linked to that work item.

*There is no way to delete work items through the web UI, and there likley never will be*

Comment: I know there is a command line tool.
The question above is for Web UI delete option.

Comment: There is no UI option for deleting work items. It is not a user but an administrator task.

Comment: Is there a reason to make administrator life so hard?
Applying simple user permissions functionality to Web UI is so difficult for Microsoft?

Comment: No: However the goal is to deter people from deleting work items as it is generally un-necessary. Your example is a corner case that is easily solved by having a training collection or team project.

Comment: I disagree with "generally un-necessary". In the example above there is reason 2: "After entering some Task work items I see later as unnecessary" and that happens often for a list of tasks that are children of a canceled or modified User Story.

Comment: Then those tasks should always be retained for traceability. You may have check-ins associated, or other meta data that should always exist. That's why there is a 'removed' state. When you 'delete' source code files or folders it does not actually 'delete' anything. It just hides that item from now on. To actually destroy it you need to drop to the command line. Same applies to Work Items. They are an organisational asset and it is not your decision (unless you are the PM/PO/CEO) to destroy evidence.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the state of the item from "To Do" to "Removed". It will then remove it from your backlog / task board.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to actually delete work items in VSO (well technically VSTS is the latest name chosen).

Open a work item > click the '...' in the top right corner > select 'delete'.